# React JS Unexpected end of JSON input error when binding data from an API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I have a select-dropdown-list, it's data is generated from a API/json file. The json resembles the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 444,
        "ggg_progid": "0000-111-222-333-44444",
        "clientName": "client 1- aaa-bb-01-05 - AA"
    }
]
```

...but I get the error, Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input, when I run my code using a particular url for the API/json file. So when I copy the code from the API and paste it into myjson.com, then use the url provided by myjson.com, my code works fine.

What could the problem be, both API's have the same json syntax?

Just in case, I provided the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Ast extends Component {

   constructor(){
       super();
       this.state = {
           data: [],
       };
   } //end constructor

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://myapi/:1234/api/clients', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer abc123def.abc123def.abc123def'
            },
        })
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))
    }

    render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="container">
            <form>
            <h2>Memeber Selection:</h2>
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.data.map(item =>(
                        <div>
                            <select className="custom-select" id="clientName">>
                            <option key={item.clientName}>{item.clientName}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
            <div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
        );
      }
}

export default Ast
```

I took the failing URL and pasted it into postman, and it renders results. Any ideal why an error is generated when I use the url in my code?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log()`-ing the data?

Comment: yes, ...and I notice a 404 error is return (url not found), however, when process the URL using postman (bearer token selected); I get results from the API. ...Any suggestion?

Comment: @ionizer, I was wondering, when processing the url via Postman, I entered a bearer token generated from the a previous API, could the issue be, that I need to pass a token in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Auth header is wrong

Change

```
'Authorization': 'abc123def.abc123def.abc123def'
```

To

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer abc123def.abc123def.abc123def'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following

```
[
    {
        "id": 444,
        "ggg_progid": "0000-111-222-333-44444",
        "clientName": "client 1- aaa-bb-01-05 - AA"
    }
]
```

to

```
{
  [
      {
        "id": 444,
        "ggg_progid": "0000-111-222-333-44444",
        "clientName": "client 1- aaa-bb-01-05 - AA"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately, I do not have direct access to the API, (The API was provided by another). Is there anything I can do in my code?

Comment: I was wondering, when processing the url via Postman, I entered a bearer token generated from the a previous API, could the issue be, that I need to pass a token in my code?

Comment: You need to pass access token for sure, yes

Comment: I modified the code I posted;  I implemented a GET method into the fetch statement and where I have authorization, I entered a token that was generated from postman, but I still get the same error. I'm new to API consumption; could you take a look at my code and let me know what am doing wrong?

Comment: Add bearer to authorization header. I posted new answer

Comment: I added bearer to authorization, but still get the same error. Is there something am over-looking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170874/discussion-between-nick-prozee-and-user1724708).

Comment: Hi Nick, if/when you have a moment, could you check out a question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50312738/react-js-error-unexpected-end-of-json-when-passing-user-token-via-session-storag/50312786?noredirect=1#comment87653792_50312786  ...let me know if could provide some assistance please. thank you