# React JS Error unexpected end of JSON when passing user token via session-storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I have a login page, which excepts the username and password. Upon button submission, the page processes the user credentials via a JSON / API and generates a token thus routing the user over to a landing that presents the client with a drop-down of their respective info.

My login page is getting the user token from the API (confirmed via console.log), but the problem I'm encountering is getting the token to pass from the login page over to the landing page.

Now, **when I manually paste the generated token into my landing page**, the dropdown list displays the user's data, so the issue is getting the generated token to pass over to the landing page.

First, in the login page, I have a function for retrieving the client's token from the API. I call this function on button submit:

```
componentDidMount() {  
    this.fetchData(); 
} 

//request the token
fetchData() {
    return fetch('http://myapiauth:11111/api/auth', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
         body: JSON.stringify({
            username: 'myadminName',
            password: 'myPassword',
            Authorization: 'myPassword',
        })
    }) /*end fetch */
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data: data })
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data))
      })
    }

  //authenticate request
  requestUserInfo() {
    var token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    return fetch('http://myapiauth:11111/api/auth', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' +sessionStorage.token
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json());
  }
```

**Login Full Code**: https://codepen.io/lkennedy009/pen/mLKPLv?editors=0010#0

...for the landing page, in the snippet below, am retrieving the token from the login page:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://myapiclients:22222/api/clients', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +sessionStorage.token
        },
    })
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))
}
```

Landing Page full code: https://codepen.io/lkennedy009/pen/ELRKpw?editors=0010#0

Could I please get some help as to what am doing wrong? I've checked my syntax / setup and compared against other online resources, but still unable to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henrik has posted, you will have to set the value to local Storage as,

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data))
```

and use it as,

```
var token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
```

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the issue as to why the token was not being stored in the session. However, my landing page still errors out: (unexpected end of json)  ...on my landing page, in the Fetch, am I using the proper syntax? I updated my coding snippet & code pen. Could you take a look please ?

Comment: Again `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +localStorage.getItem('token')` is the correct format

Comment: ok, I've re-confirmed, however, my landing page is still rendering the same error. on the landing page, when I manually copy/paste the token into the fetch, the page refreshes without errors and I see the clients data. I ensured that my headers reflect the following:         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +sessionStorage.getItem('token') ...in my function: requestUserInfo(), which is called in the Login page and in the fetch of my landing page. Could there possibly be an issue in the way I have my credentials set in the header of the fetch being used in my fetchData() function where am using post?

Comment: ...I notice in my console, that I get a 401 (Unauthorized) error in reference to the client API, so am wondering if within my Post, is my header properly formatted?

Comment: Its not, 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +`sessionStorage`.getItem('token'), its, `localStorage`. And you can verify whether you are really storing the value in your localStorage by going to the applications tab in your developer console in browser

Comment: I apologize, I applied the modifications (am now using localStorage in place of Session storage); the token is being stored, I confirmed via the application tab, but the landing page still errors out. Any other suggestions please as to what am doing wrong? I feel that am so close to resolving the issue. I updated my code-pen once more to make things a bit easier to view as far as my logic/setup; FYI-the errors am noticing in the console are 404 not found - unexpected end of json for the login page; and for the landing page: 401 - unauthorized; ...this after I enter the credentials & execute.

Comment: ...so in the Fetch - Post section - of my fetchData() function , could there be something am doing wrong as far as the Way I have my  header set up / credentials? FYI, the same credentials I use in my code, is what I tested with using postman (within the json body) ...and a token is generated. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions or if you have time to speak via chat? thank you

Comment: Its mid night here. And i was about to sleep, is it ok if we can chat about this later(if you still couldn't find a solution). And for a quick suggestion, you can cross check the header and other values of both ur fetch call and poster call using ur browser developer tool and identify the difference in both and which field you are missing since the poster call works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stringify the data into `sessionStorage`. Otherwise it's going to look like this `"[object Object]"`. This is because `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` can only store DOMStrings and not objects.
The documentation for [Storage.setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

Simple test to verify:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', {'a':1})
let t = sessionStorage.getItem('token')
// "[object Object]".
```